# Is it still necessary to verify Ubuntu (22.04 lts) ISO image download prior to install

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, lts

As best as I can find in the [installation doc](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) this is no longer part of the Install Process.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Verifying the ISO is just to confirm the integrity of the file downloaded. It is not the part of installation process

Comment: This site gets plaintive questions nearly every day from folks who are confused why their installers aren't working. It's usually because their download was corrupted or incomplete. Maybe you will be one of the 99% whose downloads are just fine...and maybe you won't. Verify the download, and you will KNOW. It's a useful check before proceeding to the next step.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from your statement that it used to be a part of the install process instructions.  Instructions for checking the signatures for the ISO are still there, but as a separate [Tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu).

It's certainly optional, and really always has been, but, as the doc says:

> While we hope you can usually trust your Ubuntu download, it is definitely reassuring to be able to verify that the image you have downloaded is not corrupted in some way, and also that it is an authentic image that hasn’t been tampered with.

I'd call it a "best practice", but one that many (even experienced) Ubuntu users probably skip.  Very similar in nature to the best practice of confirming SSH key fingerprints when connecting to a new server for the first time.  I've even seen experienced security professionals skip this.

The threat of either of these being an attack vector is low, but if you are in an environment where security is paramount, it's best to follow, well, the best practices.